# How can I bind the value of a radio button in vue.js by clicking on it's label?

Tags: css, vue.js, radio-button

Is there a way to click on the labels of a radio input to output the value?

I'm using v-model in vue.js and I've hidden my radio buttons (`input[type="radio"]{display: none;`) and I'm trying to use the value of the buttons, but when clicking on the labels instead. This isn't working

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9t41L6my/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radio buttons must have the same `name` so that they're treated as a single radio group. Also, `<label>.for` should refer to the `id` of the corresponding `<input>`, so that clicking the label would automatically select the input.

Your template should look like this:

```html
<div class="timeline__radio">
  <input id="daily" class="timeline__input" type="radio" name="timeline" value="daily" v-model="checked">
  <label for="daily" class="timeline__label">Daily</label>
</div>
<div class="timeline__radio">
  <input id="weekly" class="timeline__input" type="radio" name="timeline" value="weekly" v-model="checked">
  <label for="weekly" class="timeline__label">Weekly</label>
</div>
<div class="timeline__radio">
  <input id="monthly" class="timeline__input" type="radio" name="timeline" value="monthly" v-model="checked">
  <label for="monthly" class="timeline__label">Monthly</label>
</div>
<div class="timeline__radio">
  <input id="yearly" class="timeline__input" type="radio" name="timeline" value="yearly" v-model="checked">
  <label for="yearly" class="timeline__label">Yearly</label>
</div>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/MWJZbYW)

Answer (score 0):

Give all inputs the same name

```
name="same"
```

Give the inputs an `id` the same as the labels' `for`

```
<input id="daily" value="daily" v-model="checked" />
<label for="daily">Label</label>
```

You also want to remove `@click="checked"`

And you want to define the value for each, not bind them

```
value="daily"  // NOT :value="daily"
```

[Here is an example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<input id="daily" type="radio" name="same" value="daily" v-model="checked">
<label for="daily">Daily</label>

<input id="weekly" type="radio" name="same" value="weekly" v-model="checked">
<label for="weekly">Weekly</label>

<input id="monthly" type="radio" name="same" value="monthly" v-model="checked">
<label for="monthly">Monthly</label>

<input id="yearly" type="radio" name="same" value="yearly" v-model="checked">
<label for="yearly">Yearly</label>
```